# swiftでRSSリーダーを作成しているのですが、parserを作って<content:encoded>内のURLを取得したいです

Tags: swift

コードはこんな感じです

```
<content:encoded>
https~
<content:encoded>
```

上のURL部分を取り出して、

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

    switch elementName {

    case "item":
        parsedFeed = Feed()
        return

    case "title":
        parsedElement = "title"

    case "link":
        parsedElement = "link"

    case "enclosure":
        parsedImageURL = attributeDict["url"] as String!


    default:
        return
    }
}
```

のparsedImageURLに代入したいです
よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSXMLParserDelegate`のどのメソッドで何を処理するかが間違っているようです。
まず、`NSMutableString`型の`stringBuffer`（と、ここではしておきます）というメンバー変数を用意しておき、`didStartElement`で初期化します。
`didStartElement`は文字通りエレメントが始まった時に呼ばれるfuncなのでここではまだ`<エレメント名>`を読んだだけで、エレメントの内容に対する処理はなにも出来ることがありません。
なので、以前のデータが残らないように、ここで`stringBuffer`を初期化し、内容を読み込む準備をします。

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String, qualifiedName: String, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject])
{
    stringBuffer = String()
} // end func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String, qualifiedName: String, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

----追記----

質問主さんは`attributedDict`からリンクを抜き出そうとしていますが、`attributesDict`に入ってくるのはタグが、

```
<tag attribute1='value1' attribute2='value2' attribute3='value3'>
    tagbody
</tag>
```

という形をして、attributeを持っているとして、value*N*　を取り出したい時に、`attributesDict["attributeN"]`という形で取り出せます。
が、tagbodyを読み込んで利用したいのでしたらこの段階ではまだ不可能です。
質問主さんのxmlソースからはどちらとも判別しがたいため、対象のリンクは`<tag>`リンク`</tag>`の様に`tag`の中に平文として埋め込まれている前提で話を続けます。

----追記終わり----

次にエレメント内の内容そのものを読み込んだ時に呼ばれるのが、`foundCharacters`です。
これは改行やascii/日本語など、コンテキストの切り替わり毎に呼ばれるようで、何回呼ばれるか解らないため、受け取ったstringを`stringBuffer`に追加していき、取りこぼしが無いようにします。

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
{
    stringBuffer += string
} // end func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
```

最後に上の3行目の`</エレメント名>`(多分スラッシュが抜けているのでしょう)が来た時に呼ばれるのが`didEndElement`なので、ここで受け取ったエレメント名を元に、`foundCharlacters`で蓄積した文字列を処理します。
RSSとの事なので、URLが記載されているのは`<link>`から`</link>`タグの間でしょうから、NSString型の`targetLink`というメンバー変数を用意しておいて、

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String, qualifiedName qName: String)
{
    switch elementName {
        case "link":
            targetLink = stringBuffer
        default:
            return
    }
}// end func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String, qualifiedName qName: String) {
```

として`stringBuffer`に溜め込まれ、繋げられたURL文字列をコピーします。
これでパーサーの処理が終わった後に`targetLink`というメンバー変数にアクセスすればリンクのURLが取得できると思います。